# How to solve this definite integral in finding the expectation

Tags: integration

I have been trying to find the $E[\ln (1+x)]$, but am stuck in this step:

$\ln(1+x) F_X(x) \mid_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty F_X(x) \dfrac{1}{1+x}$

where $F_X(x)$ is a CDF and is given as $1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + ax}\exp^\left( -\dfrac{x}{b} \right)$

Comment: Where are you stuck "exactly"?

Comment: $\ln(1+x)F_X(x)  \mid_0^\infty = ?$ and $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{1+x}$ =?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck because of an earlier misstep. We know that
$$\begin{align}E[\ln(1+x)]&=\int_0^{\infty}f_X(x)\ln(1+x)dx\\
&=\left.-\frac1{1+ax}e^{-x/b}\ln(1+x)\right|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x/b}dx}{(1+x)(1+ax)}\\
&=\frac1{1-a}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac1{1+x}-\frac a{1+ax}\right)e^{-x/b}dx\end{align}$$
Note that we chose a constant of integration such that the integrated term stayed finite. Now we could work this a little farther to
$$E[\ln(1+x)]=\frac1{1-a}\left(e^{1/ab}\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\frac1{ab}\right)-e^{-1/b}\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\frac1b\right)\right)$$
Where $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) function.

Comment: How did you get $f_X(x) = - \dfrac{1}{1+ax} e^{-x/b}$?

Comment: I didn't get that. I got $f_X(x)=\frac d{dx}F_X(x)$ so $\int f_X(x)dx=F_X(x)+C$. I chose $C=-1$ so as to avoid the divergences encountered in your question.

Comment: Can you point out any resources from where I can read about this divergence

Comment: Well, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(1+x)=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F_X(x)=1$$ So that's your divergence. However, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\ln(1+x)\left(F_X(x)-1\right)\right)=0$$ And that avoids the divergence.